# Phonegap Local Storage - File API

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, local-storage

my app is not able to write files to the local storage. I followed the API [documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_file_file.md.html#LocalFileSystem). My code is:

```
/*
 * 
 * Device Ready
 * 
 */

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

//Crodova is ready
function onDeviceReady() {
    // Now safe to use device APIs
    //Load the main html on startup
    loadContent("main.html");
    //Prepare to laod the seetings and history file
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, failFS);

}
/*
*
* The File Storage
*
*/
could, know all old GPS positions
function gotFS() {
    fileSystem.root.getFile("readme.txt", {create: true, exclusive: false}, gotFileEntry, fail);
}

function failFS(error) {
    console.log(error.code);
}

function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
    fileEntry.createWriter(gotFileWriter, fail);
}

function gotFileWriter(writer) {
    writer.onwriteend = function(evt) {
        console.log("contents of file now 'some sample text'");
        writer.truncate(11);  
        writer.onwriteend = function(evt) {
            console.log("contents of file now 'some sample'");
            writer.seek(4);
            writer.write(" different text");
            writer.onwriteend = function(evt){
                console.log("contents of file now 'some different text'");
            }
        };
    };
    writer.write("some sample text");
}
```

I am using the android emulator and with logcat I get the following output:

```
[linux@linux ~]$ adb logcat *:S CordovaLog:D
--------- beginning of /dev/log/system
--------- beginning of /dev/log/main
D/CordovaLog( 1101): file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js: Line 164 : code: 3
D/CordovaLog( 1101): message: Timeout expired
D/CordovaLog( 1101): file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js: Line 164 : code: 3
D/CordovaLog( 1101): message: Timeout expired
D/CordovaLog( 1101): file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js: Line 164 : code: 3
D/CordovaLog( 1101): message: Timeout expired
D/CordovaLog( 1101): file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js: Line 164 : code: 3
D/CordovaLog( 1101): message: Timeout expired
D/CordovaLog( 1101): file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js: Line 164 : code: 3
D/CordovaLog( 1101): message: Timeout expired
D/CordovaLog( 1101): file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js: Line 164 : code: 3
D/CordovaLog( 1101): message: Timeout expired
D/CordovaLog( 1101): file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js: Line 164 : code: 3
D/CordovaLog( 1101): message: Timeout expired
D/CordovaLog( 1101): file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js: Line 164 : code: 3
D/CordovaLog( 1101): message: Timeout expired
D/CordovaLog( 1101): file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js: Line 164 : code: 3
D/CordovaLog( 1101): message: Timeout expired
I/CordovaLog( 1286): Changing log level to DEBUG(3)
D/CordovaLog( 1286): file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js: Line 1169 : deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds.
D/CordovaLog( 1286): file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js: Line 1162 : Channel not fired: onPluginsReady
D/CordovaLog( 1286): file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js: Line 1162 : Channel not fired: onCordovaReady
D/CordovaLog( 1286): file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js: Line 43 : main.html
D/CordovaLog( 1286): file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js: Line 1059 : processMessage failed: Error: ReferenceError: fileSystem is not defined
D/CordovaLog( 1286): file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js: Line 1060 : processMessage failed: Stack: ReferenceError: fileSystem is not defined
D/CordovaLog( 1286):     at gotFS (file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js:306:5)
D/CordovaLog( 1286):     at file:///android_asset/www/plugins/org.apache.cordova.file/www/requestFileSystem.js:53:25
D/CordovaLog( 1286):     at success (file:///android_asset/www/plugins/org.apache.cordova.file/www/fileSystems-roots.js:40:13)
D/CordovaLog( 1286):     at Object.cordova.callbackFromNative (file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js:293:54)
D/CordovaLog( 1286):     at processMessage (file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js:1054:21)
D/CordovaLog( 1286):     at Function.androidExec.processMessages (file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js:1091:13)
D/CordovaLog( 1286):     at pollOnce (file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js:956:17)
D/CordovaLog( 1286):     at pollOnceFromOnlineEvent (file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js:946:5)
D/CordovaLog( 1286): file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js: Line 1061 : processMessage failed: Message: S01 File1368220044 [{"fullPath":"\/","filesystemName":"temporary","isDirectory":true,"nativeURL":"file:\/\/\/data\/data\/com.phonegap.helloworld\/cache\/","filesystem":0,"isFile":false,"name":""},{"fullPath":"\/","filesystemName":"persistent","isDirectory":true,"nativeURL":"file:\/\/\/data\/data\/com.phonegap.helloworld\/","filesystem":1,"isFile":false,"name":""},{"fullPath":"\/","filesystemName":"content","isDirectory":true,"nativeURL":"content:\/\/","filesystem":1,"isFile":false,"name":""},{"fullPath":"\/","filesystemName":"files","isDirectory":true,"nativeURL":"file:\/\/\/data\/data\/com.phonegap.helloworld\/files\/","filesystem":1,"isFile":false,"name":""},{"fullPath":"\/","filesystemName":"documents","isDirectory":true,"nativeURL":"file:\/\/\/data\/data\/com.phonegap.helloworld\/files\/Documents\/","filesystem":1,"isFile":false,"name":""},{"fullPath":"\/","filesystemName":"cache","isDirectory":true,"nativeURL":"file:\/\/\/data\/data\/com.phonegap.helloworld\/cache\/","filesystem":1,"isFile":false,"name":""},{"fullPath":"\/","filesystemName":"root","isDirectory":true,"nativeURL":"file:\/\/\/","filesystem":1,"isFile":false,"name":""}]
D/CordovaLog( 1286): file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js: Line 43 : run.html
D/CordovaLog( 1286): file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js: Line 43 : run.html
D/CordovaLog( 1286): file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js: Line 164 : code: 3
D/CordovaLog( 1286): message: Timeout expired
D/CordovaLog( 1286): file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js: Line 164 : code: 3
D/CordovaLog( 1286): message: Timeout expired
D/CordovaLog( 1286): file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js: Line 164 : code: 3
D/CordovaLog( 1286): message: Timeout expired
D/CordovaLog( 1286): file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js: Line 164 : code: 3
D/CordovaLog( 1286): message: Timeout expired
D/CordovaLog( 1286): file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js: Line 164 : code: 3
D/CordovaLog( 1286): message: Timeout expired
D/CordovaLog( 1286): file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js: Line 164 : code: 3
D/CordovaLog( 1286): message: Timeout expired
D/CordovaLog( 1286): file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js: Line 164 : code: 3
D/CordovaLog( 1286): message: Timeout expired
D/CordovaLog( 1286): file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js: Line 164 : code: 3
D/CordovaLog( 1286): message: Timeout expired
D/CordovaLog( 1286): file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js: Line 164 : code: 3
D/CordovaLog( 1286): message: Timeout expired
D/CordovaLog( 1286): file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js: Line 164 : code: 3
D/CordovaLog( 1286): message: Timeout expired
D/CordovaLog( 1286): file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js: Line 164 : code: 3
D/CordovaLog( 1286): message: Timeout expired
D/CordovaLog( 1286): file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js: Line 164 : code: 3
D/CordovaLog( 1286): message: Timeout expired
I/CordovaLog( 1286): Changing log level to DEBUG(3)
D/CordovaLog( 1286): file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js: Line 1169 : deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds.
D/CordovaLog( 1286): file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js: Line 1162 : Channel not fired: onDOMContentLoaded
D/CordovaLog( 1286): file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js: Line 43 : main.html
D/CordovaLog( 1286): file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js: Line 1059 : processMessage failed: Error: ReferenceError: fileSystem is not defined
D/CordovaLog( 1286): file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js: Line 1060 : processMessage failed: Stack: ReferenceError: fileSystem is not defined
D/CordovaLog( 1286):     at gotFS (file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js:306:5)
D/CordovaLog( 1286):     at file:///android_asset/www/plugins/org.apache.cordova.file/www/requestFileSystem.js:53:25
D/CordovaLog( 1286):     at success (file:///android_asset/www/plugins/org.apache.cordova.file/www/fileSystems-roots.js:40:13)
D/CordovaLog( 1286):     at Object.cordova.callbackFromNative (file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js:293:54)
D/CordovaLog( 1286):     at processMessage (file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js:1054:21)
D/CordovaLog( 1286):     at Function.androidExec.processMessages (file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js:1091:13)
D/CordovaLog( 1286):     at pollOnce (file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js:956:17)
D/CordovaLog( 1286):     at pollOnceFromOnlineEvent (file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js:946:5)
D/CordovaLog( 1286): file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js: Line 1061 : processMessage failed: Message: S01 File476869768 [{"fullPath":"\/","filesystemName":"temporary","isDirectory":true,"nativeURL":"file:\/\/\/data\/data\/com.phonegap.helloworld\/cache\/","filesystem":0,"isFile":false,"name":""},{"fullPath":"\/","filesystemName":"persistent","isDirectory":true,"nativeURL":"file:\/\/\/data\/data\/com.phonegap.helloworld\/","filesystem":1,"isFile":false,"name":""},{"fullPath":"\/","filesystemName":"content","isDirectory":true,"nativeURL":"content:\/\/","filesystem":1,"isFile":false,"name":""},{"fullPath":"\/","filesystemName":"files","isDirectory":true,"nativeURL":"file:\/\/\/data\/data\/com.phonegap.helloworld\/files\/","filesystem":1,"isFile":false,"name":""},{"fullPath":"\/","filesystemName":"documents","isDirectory":true,"nativeURL":"file:\/\/\/data\/data\/com.phonegap.helloworld\/files\/Documents\/","filesystem":1,"isFile":false,"name":""},{"fullPath":"\/","filesystemName":"cache","isDirectory":true,"nativeURL":"file:\/\/\/data\/data\/com.phonegap.helloworld\/cache\/","filesystem":1,"isFile":false,"name":""},{"fullPath":"\/","filesystemName":"root","isDirectory":true,"nativeURL":"file:\/\/\/","filesystem":1,"isFile":false,"name":""}]
D/CordovaLog( 1286): file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js: Line 164 : code: 3
D/CordovaLog( 1286): message: Timeout expired
D/CordovaLog( 1286): file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js: Line 164 : code: 3
D/CordovaLog( 1286): message: Timeout expired
D/CordovaLog( 1286): file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js: Line 164 : code: 3
D/CordovaLog( 1286): message: Timeout expired
D/CordovaLog( 1286): file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js: Line 164 : code: 3
D/CordovaLog( 1286): message: Timeout expired
D/CordovaLog( 1286): file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js: Line 164 : code: 3
D/CordovaLog( 1286): message: Timeout expired
D/CordovaLog( 1286): file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js: Line 164 : code: 3
D/CordovaLog( 1286): message: Timeout expired
D/CordovaLog( 1286): file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js: Line 164 : code: 3
D/CordovaLog( 1286): message: Timeout expired
D/CordovaLog( 1286): file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js: Line 164 : code: 3
D/CordovaLog( 1286): message: Timeout expired
D/CordovaLog( 1286): file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js: Line 164 : code: 3
D/CordovaLog( 1286): message: Timeout expired
D/CordovaLog( 1286): file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js: Line 164 : code: 3
D/CordovaLog( 1286): message: Timeout expired
D/CordovaLog( 1286): file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js: Line 164 : code: 3
D/CordovaLog( 1286): message: Timeout expired
D/CordovaLog( 1286): file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js: Line 164 : code: 3
D/CordovaLog( 1286): message: Timeout expired
D/CordovaLog( 1286): file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js: Line 164 : code: 3
D/CordovaLog( 1286): message: Timeout expired
D/CordovaLog( 1286): file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js: Line 164 : code: 3
D/CordovaLog( 1286): message: Timeout expired
D/CordovaLog( 1286): file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js: Line 164 : code: 3
D/CordovaLog( 1286): message: Timeout expired
D/CordovaLog( 1286): file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js: Line 164 : code: 3
D/CordovaLog( 1286): message: Timeout expired
D/CordovaLog( 1286): file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js: Line 164 : code: 3
D/CordovaLog( 1286): message: Timeout expired
D/CordovaLog( 1286): file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js: Line 164 : code: 3
D/CordovaLog( 1286): message: Timeout expired
D/CordovaLog( 1286): file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js: Line 164 : code: 3
D/CordovaLog( 1286): message: Timeout expired
D/CordovaLog( 1286): file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js: Line 164 : code: 3
D/CordovaLog( 1286): message: Timeout expired
D/CordovaLog( 1286): file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js: Line 164 : code: 3
D/CordovaLog( 1286): message: Timeout expired
D/CordovaLog( 1286): file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js: Line 164 : code: 3
D/CordovaLog( 1286): message: Timeout expired
D/CordovaLog( 1286): file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js: Line 164 : code: 3
D/CordovaLog( 1286): message: Timeout expired
D/CordovaLog( 1286): file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js: Line 164 : code: 3
D/CordovaLog( 1286): message: Timeout expired
D/CordovaLog( 1286): file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js: Line 164 : code: 3
D/CordovaLog( 1286): message: Timeout expired
D/CordovaLog( 1286): file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js: Line 164 : code: 3
D/CordovaLog( 1286): message: Timeout expired
D/CordovaLog( 1286): file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js: Line 164 : code: 3
D/CordovaLog( 1286): message: Timeout expired
D/CordovaLog( 1286): file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js: Line 164 : code: 3
D/CordovaLog( 1286): message: Timeout expired
D/CordovaLog( 1286): file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js: Line 164 : code: 3
D/CordovaLog( 1286): message: Timeout expired
```

I have build the app with the `phonegap build` command and then emulated it, but I do not know why it is not saving anything. I also cannot find any new data in the `/data/user/0/com.phonegap.helloworld` directory.

Comment: Can you check if your app has write permissions on that location?

Comment: @Sam in the `Androidmanifest.xml` the following is included `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` and also `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />` and `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />`